# I pulled the source code of slf4 from github, but I can't run it in IDEA

Tags: java, slf4j

I am researching the code implementation for slf4j. How do I run a simple test when I pull the source code for `slf4j`?

I created a new module in the source code project of slf4j. In this module, I introduced the `slf4j-api` module and the `sl4j-simple` module.

```java
// The code inside my module
public class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Demo.class);
    logger.error("haha");
  }
}
```

**my pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <artifactId>slf4j-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <version>1.7.28</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This prompt appears after running my code：

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Comment: The error "Failed to load class" is itself mentioned in the document you have mentioned. Just go through it and apply the approach mentioned there. I guess it will work

Comment: However, the module I created has introduced the slf4j-api module and the slf4j-sample module, but he still suggests that I don't have a specific implementation of slf4j.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these to help troubleshoot:

- Use Java 8.
- Specify a slf4j version < 1.8 in your dependencies.

It seems you are running into classpath issues related to `jigsaw`.

Comment: The pulled slf4j version is 1.7.28, using jdk8.

Comment: Are you sure IDEA is **debugging** using 1.8?  Check your project JDK settings.

Comment: I got slf4j 1.7.28 on github before, but now I have got slf4j 1.7.24 on github, and it is working now.Thank you very much for your help. I think there is something wrong with my IDEA, and I am trying to find out the answer.

Comment: @L.gen Your launch configuration when debugging uses a specified JDK and classpath.  This is different from the JDK in your project settings.

Comment: I set the JDK to 1.8 in IDEA's Project Structure->project.